# how to play dual audio movies in wpf c#

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mediaelement

The basic WPF media-element just play the MKV file but does't seek and provide facility to change audio.

Is it possible to play this type of videos in Media-element. I have searched so many Que... on stackoverflow like extending media-element functionality etc. or using third party component but does't find any suitable SOLUTION.

**I does't mean you tell me a complete tutorial but just only gives me direction, what should I do or what can be the alternative?**

**I don't want to use c++ because I like WPF Graphics**

Can somebody help me ?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use some C# VLC interface, it will provide you with a lot more options than built in `MediaElement`.

One of such is [Vlc.DotNet](https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet), it has NuGet package for WPF (`Vlc.DotNet.Wpf`), and lets you do anything that you could do from command line (that is, anything you could do in standalone VLC) so changing audio tracks will not pose any problem.

Comment: I think this will require vlc media player  installation ?

Comment: It does not, it uses `libvlc`, that is C library that VLC uses. So it provides all functionalities of VLC, without VLC itself

Comment: Ok I will try and then replay to you.