# FFmpegInterop.UWP or VLC.MediaElement for UWP apps

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, uwp, vlc

Which one is better choice for UWP? VLC is really easy to start to use but FFmpeg more complicated (read: difficult). But if we are thinking for example licenses, support of different format, casting, media tags, converting , subtitles and audio support, video/audio editing etc.

Any experiences?

Comment: Related que. I had asked few days. See  here https://stackoverflow.com/q/51961420/9345155     I found vlc.dotnet for me, it is simple, free, support wpf as well as  winforms and you can play wide range of formats like vlc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vlc.DotNet does not run with UWP.

I'd advise you to use https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement which uses a C++/CX wrapper under the hood to call libvlc. That's a rather complete sample app: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-winrt

> licenses, support of different format, casting, media tags, converting , subtitles and audio support, video/audio editing

That's a lot of considerations and I don't know your requirements and needs. You should evaluate both. But for ease of use, VLC.MediaElement is the best choice.

Comment: Yes, VLC.MediaElement looks best choice so far. It is most easier to bring into use. It looks support most of all 'normal' formats + many others also. Big plus comes that it need quite minimum changes to code if used WindowsMediaElement before. If cast doesn't works as is should it is possible to use  WindowsMediaElement in those cases. Anyway WindowsMediaElement  do this very well. Primary problem with WindowsMediaElement  is that it doesn't support even most common formats (yet).

Answer (score 0):

Vlc Dot net . you can find details here https://github.com/ZeBobo5/Vlc.DotNet
This library will provide you better control. There are many other choices but as you are talking about audio/video/subtitles/formats you will find everything in this library. This is core medial lib and wrap by custom control.

Thus can be easily import in any wpf project/ Uwp project.

Comment: Editing is a different aspect , depends what type of editing you want like audio-video or equaliser manage like or triming etc. It is better you should define editing to find better ans...  what you mean editing like triming, cropping etc.

Comment: Editing is just something simple like triming, cropping etc.

Comment: It's also important to convert video to other format and change the resolution.

Comment: Does VLC support (de)mux. It would be nice to mux subtitles into the video file.

Comment: I don't understand why'd you need 3rd party libraries for simple trimming? Windows.Media.Composition namespace can do that nicely.

Comment: The problem itself isn't trimming , the primary problem is that Windows itself supports only few video / audio formats. They even drop HEVC codec away and still common mpeg2 is unsupported also. But if I make app using VLC or FFmpeg I can get support for many media formats. And if those api has cropping / trimming (or others editing included) it is good thing. All in one makes life easier.